# JQuery pass the first "." character of a filename and return the file name value

Tags: jquery, string, data-structures

I am using `<input type="file" id="myfile">` and there is a file format on it.

for example `mytestfile1.imagefile.jpg` or `mytestfile2.documentfile.docx`

what I am trying to do is to get the name of the file example:

`mytestfile1.imagefile` or `mytestfile2.documentfile`

for now my code is like this:

`alert($('#myfile').val().split('.').shift());`

but I got only `mytestfile1` or `mytestfile2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift()` will just return the first element of the array, but you want the first *two* elements. Use `slice()` to get multiple elements.

```
alert($('#myfile').val().split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.'));
```

If you want to allow for any number of filename components before the suffix, you can use a negative end-index with `slice()`:

```
alert($('#myfile').val().split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.lastIndexOf() to get the last instance of the '.', and then use substring to get the relevant portion. For instance:

```
function ext(s){
    return s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
console.log(ext("helloworld.foo.bar.txt"));
```

would return `helloworld.foo.bar`